# Cómo soluciono este loop infinito React?

Tags: array, reactjs

Lo que quiero hacer es que me obtenga una lista de los archivos en la memoria interna para poder procesarlos despues, pero no logro quitar ese loop, con push si funciona pero yo lo que quiero es que actualice automaticamente una lista en otra tab. Gracias por la ayuda

```
const [Lalista, setArrayHolder] = React.useState([]);


const main = () =>{

    useEffect(() => {
      listaImagen()
 }),[];

 
 
 const listaImagen = async () =>{

   const album = await MediaLibrary.getAlbumAsync("DCIM");
 
   const fotos = await MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync(album);
   
   
     for(let i=0; i<fotos.assets.length; i++){
      setArrayHolder([... Lalista, {uri: fotos.assets[0].uri}]);
     }

     console.log(Lalista)

     
  }


 return(
....

)
```

La salida infinita es esta

```
Array [
  Object {
    "uri": "file:///storage/emulated/0/IMG_20210721_010648.jpg",
  },
]
Array [
  Object {
    "uri": "file:///storage/emulated/0/IMG_20210721_010648.jpg",
  },
]
Array [
  Object {
    "uri": "file:///storage/emulated/0/IMG_20210721_010648.jpg",
  },
```

Comment: En principio estás obteniendo la misma ruta de imagen siempre: `fotos.assets[0].uri`. Si tu intención es recorrer la lista `assets`, entonces dentro de ese bucle has de escribir el iterando `i` en vez del `0`. Por ejemplo: `fotos.assets[i].uri`. Empieza por corregir ese error y comenta el resultado.

Comment: Ya hice la modificación que me dices y ya no me muestra el mismo valor siempre, pero el ciclo sigue siendo infinito

Comment: No tengo experiencia en React, pero yo miraría la lógica de esta sentencia: `setArrayHolder([... Lalista, {uri: fotos.assets[i].uri}]);`. Tal vez hay algún detalle de la implementación que genera una recursión en dicho método y como estás usando el operador `spread` para pasar la lista, tal vez se quede pillado por allí. Podrías primero hacer `push` del elemento: `Lalista.push({uri: fotos.assets[i].uri});` y luego usar el método: `setArrayHolder(Lalista);`. Toma en cuenta que este comentario lo hago desde mi desconocimiento de React. Saludos

Comment: Gracias hermano! Funcionó a la perfección, no sé cómo calificar aquí pero te sacaste 10/10

Comment: Puedes crear tu propia respuesta y explicar cómo lograste la solución. Eso es totalmente válido, incluso pasadas 24 horas desde que publiques tu respuesta la puedes aceptar como válida. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Hice un push primero a un array vacio y despues solo fue llamar al metodo setArrayHolder pasandole como parametro la lista que se le había hecho push

```
var listaAlt = []
for(let i=0; i<fotos.assets.length; i++){
       listaAlt.push({uri: fotos.assets[i].uri})
     }

setArrayHolder(listaAlt)
```